# Rails 6 Production Active Storage NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, production, rails-activestorage

I have issue when try to attach image using Active Storage
It passed on development mode, but fail in production mode.

Details as below:

Model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
    
    validates :title, presence: true
    
    has_many :post_comments, dependent: :destroy

    has_one_attached :wall_picture
    
    # validates :content_rich_text, presence: true
    has_rich_text :content_rich_text
    
    def self.approved
      where(approved: :true)
    end
end
```

Controller:

```
def create
        @post = Post.new(post_param)
        @post.save!
        redirect_to posts_path
   end
private
    # define param for each post
    def post_param
        params.require(:post).permit(:id, :wall_picture, :title, :content_rich_text)
    end
```

Storage config:

```
google:
    service: GCS
    project: pet-app
    credentials: <%= Rails.root.join("config/pet-app-google-storage-key.json") %>
    bucket: pet-app
```

Log in development(create oject success):

```
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"IssIp0Mhh90gl9pwuuDfMdrCYz5Rf6gxMlv/WbTe6dAWye25eWAMjfhp135CqGlZj6bCYgvslQHX75yoyn/Sqw==", "post"=>{"wall_picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f05559da830 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20210328-169-j5mnl3.jpg>, @original_filename="cover_building.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[wall_picture]\"; filename=\"cover_building.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "title"=>"Test new post", "content_rich_text"=>""}, "commit"=>"Gửi nội dung"}
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:13:in `create'
  Post Exists? (0.8ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" IS NOT NULL AND "posts"."slug" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["slug", "test-new-post"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:13:in `create'
  Post Create (3.7ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("title", "created_at", "updated_at", "slug") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["title", "Test new post"], ["created_at", "2021-03-28 09:57:04.803702"], ["updated_at", "2021-03-28 09:57:04.803702"], ["slug", "test-new-post"]]
```

Log in Production( i'm using Digital Ocean Droplet with Ubuntu 20.04)

```
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"d1OTNiyXbvamUEUUUfc9hL1x1Biyh/bJf8NFz99HkTnXNIohTUsn4alNeimiR4o/syG7/NpKCvoSufbVaCp/+A==", "post"=>{"wall_picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000563231456050 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20210328-32996-ott8bf.jpg>, @original_filename="cover_building.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[wall_picture]\"; filename=\"cover_building.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "title"=>"Test new post", "content_rich_text"=>""}, "commit"=>"Gửi nội dung"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 934)

**NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):**
```

app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:12:in `create'

Can some one help me known why I get this problem in production and how to solve it? Thank you so much!

Comment: `@post.save!` will raise a `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` exception if there are any validation errors. While that can be helpful for debugging or seed files invalid user input is not an exceptional event. Use `if @post.save; redirect_to posts_path; else; render :new; end`. This is also covered by pretty much any basic rails tutorial. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-article

Comment: I also using post.save instead post.save! for this case, but the issue occur again. I think the cause may be related with ruby 3.0.0 in rails 6.1.3. Do you known another way for save image of model post? thank so much.

Comment: Did you actually check the return value and respond accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

Remember to config your service in `config/environments/production.rb` too.

```
# Store files locally.
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

... `:local` or any other service you decide to use in production

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#disk-service